# Convert decimal to number in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

I'm trying to retrieve a NumberDecimal as a number from aggregate in node.js. Here's my schema:

```
// Users
{"_id": 1, "avg": "10.1"}
{"_id": 2, "avg": "4.3"}
{"_id": 3, "avg": "8.04"}

// Posts
{"_id": 1, "title": "Besty", "userId": 3 }
{"_id": 2, "title": "another", "userId": 1 }
{"_id": 3, "title": "sample", "userId": 2 }
```

where `avg` outputs as NumberDecimal. I'm using the following pipeline to retrieve the values

```
{ $lookup: { from: 'users', localField: 'userId', foreignField: '_id', as: 'userId' } },
{ $unwind: { path: '$userId' } },
{ $project: { _id: 1, 'userId._id': 1, userId.avg: 1 } },
```

How can I make the output of `userId.avg` to be a number and not a NumberDecimal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [$toDecimal](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDecimal) Converts a value to a decimal. If the value cannot be converted to a decimal, `$toDecimal` errors. If the value is null or missing, `$toDecimal` returns null,

```
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      "userId._id": 1,
      "userId.avg": {
        $toDecimal: "$userId.avg"
      }
    }
  }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/taifZcFFmBX)